# Dependency Injection/IoC within Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I am trying to improve my spark skills and currently working on a generic Spark Streaming job.
The Job assumes that there will be a Flume like pipeline for ingesting data into other databases/storage systems => read -> deserialize -> split -> serialize -> sink to whatever systems.

When implementing that out of 'context of spark', there will be a class requiring the implementation of deserializer, splitter, serializer and sink.

But spark needs to serialize its tasks to be able to distribute them across the cluster, so - afaik - it's not a good idea to pass instances of classes into spark task closures.

Now my question is how dependency injection a la guice/spring/whatever will do its job so the components that have to be injected will be available at the executors instead of the driver?
Are there any example jobs where I can see how DI will be done with spark?

There is a link at the official spark website (http://spark.apache.org/documentation.html) to a talk about abstraction of spark jobs. The speaker mentioned DI and the usage of guice but the code shown is very high level and didn't show how that integrates into the whole setup.
https://youtu.be/C7gWtxelYNM?list=PL-x35fyliRwiP3YteXbnhk0QGOtYLBT3a&t=2002

Any hints will be awesome!